# How to run fibonacci function async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I learn node.js and I have problem with async fibonacci function.

In book example is without ES6, but I use ES6 in my example. Maybe it is a problem.

My code:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

const fibonacciAsync = exports.fibonacciAsync = (n, done) => {
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) {
    done(1);
  } else {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      fibonacciAsync(n - 1, (val1) => {
        process.nextTick(() => {
          fibonacciAsync(n - 2, (val2) => {
            done(val1 + val2);
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const urlP = url.parse(req.url, true);
  let fibo;
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  if (urlP.query['n']) {
    fibo = fibonacciAsync(urlP.query['n']);
    res.end('Fibonacci ' + urlP.query['n'] + '=' + fibo);
  } 
}).listen(8124, '127.0.0.1');
```

This returns me the error:

> TypeError: done is not a function in "done(val1 + val2);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script contains this line: `fibo = fibonacciAsync(urlP.query['n']);` which is a call to the function `fibonacciAsync`. The functions takes two arguments: `n` and `done` (which is a callback function).
Your call to this function contains only one argument, which is the `n` one, and the `done` function is `undefined`. So of course, `done` is not a `function` - it's `undefined`.

**Edit:**
For your request: I hope this will work for you.

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const urlP = url.parse(req.url, true);
  let fibo;
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  if (urlP.query['n']) {
    fibonacciAsync(urlP.query['n'], function(data) {
        res.end('Fibonacci ' + urlP.query['n'] + '=' + data);
    });
  } 
}).listen(8124, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I edited my post and added an example. I hope it will work for you :)